# JavaScript proper prototypical inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I've been spending my past couple hours researching prototypical inheritance, but I'm left with conflicting/unclear answers on how it should be done. It seems to be *working* for how I'm using it right now.

```
Paper.Component = function(){}; // useless unless I can solve problem mentioned below?
Paper.Component.prototype = {
    isInBounds: function(x, y){
        // ...
    },
    setPosition: function(x, y){
        // ...
    },
    setSize: function(w, h){
        // ...
    }
};

Paper.Button = function(x, y, w, h, text){
    // ...
}
Paper.Button.prototype = Object.create(Paper.Component.prototype);
```

It also seems to have another problem; How can I have `Paper.Button` save it's constructor information (`x,y,w,h`) onto `Paper.Component` rather than on itself? I.e., how can every child of `Paper.Component` inherit and set these values?

Comment: Maybe the following answer will be of interest to you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have so far is fine. The missing bit in `Button` looks like this:

```
Paper.Button = function(x, y, w, h, text){
    Paper.Component.call(this, /*...any args required by it...*/);

    // Button stuff here...
};
```

`Function#call` calls a function with a specific `this` value and any arguments you pass it. So the above calls `Paper.Component` from within `Paper.Button` with `this` referencing the current object, and passing along any appropriate arguments.

You also want to set the `constructor` property on any prototype you replace rather than just adding to. It's largely optional (JavaScript itself doesn't use `constructor` for anything), but since the JavaScript engine sets it on the default prototype objects, we should set it when replacing them, just so we're consistent with the default prototypes.

Slightly simpler, concrete example:

```
function Shape(sides, color) {
    this.sides = sides;
    this.color = color;
}
// Shape.prototype.method = ...

function Rectangle(color) {
    Shape.call(this, 4, color);

    // Rectangle stuff here...
}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;          // <== The constructor bit
// Rectangle.prototype.method = ...
```

---

If you're interested in setting up hierarchies of "classes" of objects using prototypical inheritance in JavaScript, you might want to look at my [`Lineage`](https://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) helper script, which automates the above with a simpler syntax and provides other useful features.

Comment: Very well explained, thank you. If I ever run into the need to provide exclusively functions to inherited objects, would the constructor just be an empty function as seen in my original post? `Paper.Component = function(){};` I've tried `Paper.Component = {};`, but I cannot seem to add a prototype to that?

Comment: @John: If you like, yes, and if you're building hierarchies with constructor functions (as you are), that's probably best. Alternately, you don't actually need the `Component` function, you could just have an object you use to create the `Button` prototype (and then have `Button` not call it). But it's probably best to be consistent.

Comment: @John: *"I've tried `Paper.Component = {};`, but I cannot seem to add a prototype to that?"* You were adding that as I was commenting above. Yes, that's what I meant. At that point, `Paper.Component` would *be* the object you'd use with `Object.create` to create the `Button` prototype: `Paper.Button.prototype = Object.create(Paper.Component);` (and you'd put `isInBounds` and such directly on `Paper.Component`). But I would probably stick with the empty function, for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

A good reference is the [MDN - Inheritance revisited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited) page

What you are looking for (I think) is something like this:

```
Paper.Component = function(x,y,w,h){
    this.setPosition( x, y );
    this.setSize( w, h );
}; 
Paper.Component.prototype.isInBounds  = function(x, y){};
Paper.Component.prototype.setPosition = function(x, y){};
Paper.Component.prototype.setSize     = function(w, h){};

Paper.Button = function(x, y, w, h, text){
    Paper.Component.apply( this, arguments );
}
Paper.Button.prototype = Object.create(Paper.Component.prototype);
Paper.Button.prototype.constructor = Paper.Button;
```

Things to note:

- Do not do `Paper.Component.prototype = { ... }` as it will overwrite the current prototype (e.g. the existing `.prototype.constructor` and anything else anyone has already created).
- Remember to set the constructor (the last line).